# Parsing data with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I make script for bash, but I need to help with one part of the script. I have values in this format

```
1,12, 3,70, 2,29
1,12, 3,78, 2,79
1,12, 3,27, 2,25
```

and I need to convert to this format

```
1.12 3.70 2.29
...
...
```

So I need to change comma for dot, and remove comma behind the number. I would like to do it with awk, but I have no idea how to do it. I can to parse it to 3 different file, and then split to one by command `paste` , but I would like to do it more effective. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/,\([0-9]\)/.\1/g;s/,//g;' file
1.12 3.70 2.29
1.12 3.78 2.79
1.12 3.27 2.25
```

This is basically 2 phase approach where 1st operation replaces commas that are followed by digit with dot and 2nd operation just strips remaining commas.

Comment: Actually i get the clue from your's answer. +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pE '$_=~s/(\d+),(\d+)/$1.$2/g; $_=~s/,//g'
```

Comment: Can probably be reduced to `perl -lpe '$_=~s/(\d+),(\d+),*/$1.$2/g' file`

Answer (score 2):

This sed command will also work,

```
sed 's/, / /g;s/,/./g' file
```

- `s/, / /g` - replaces comma and space with space only.
- `s/,/./g` - From the output of above command, it replaces `,` with `.`

Example:

```
$ echo "1,12, 3,70, 2,29" | sed 's/, / /g;s/,/./g'
1.12 3.70 2.29
```

Comment: No need to escape spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F', ' '{$1=$1;gsub(/,/,".")}1' file
1.12 3.70 2.29
1.12 3.78 2.79
1.12 3.27 2.25
```

- Set the Field Separator to comma and space.
- Re-construct the entire line to allow fields to be separated by default `OFS` (space).
- Using `gsub` replace the `,` to `.`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {printf "%s.%s", $i, $(i+1)}; print ""}' <<END
1,12, 3,70, 2,29
1,12, 3,78, 2,79
1,12, 3,27, 2,25
END
```

```
1.12 3.70 2.29
1.12 3.78 2.79
1.12 3.27 2.25
```

Answer (score 0):

and this works, too. with the -e option you can add sed commands to the same instance:

```
sed -e s/", "/" "/g -e s/","/./g file1
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` solution.

```
awk '{sub(/, /," ");gsub(/,/,".")}1' file
1.12 3.70. 2.29
1.12 3.78. 2.79
1.12 3.27. 2.25
```